# While loop in Singleton instead of if block

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

I came across the below code as part of creating a singleton using DoubleLocking

```
public static ThreadSafeSingleton getInstanceUsingDoubleLocking(){
    while(instance == null){
        synchronized (ThreadSafeSingleton.class) {
            while(instance == null){
                instance = new ThreadSafeSingleton();
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

What is the significance of using `while loop` instead of the usual `if block`? Is it due to some `JMM issues` which might affect the singleton creation in Multi Threaded Environment?

Comment: That's just unnecessary. It will only loop once, so it's equivalent to if.

Comment: The thing about double-checked locking is it can be quite hard to get right (to the extent that even Josh Bloch got it wrong in the first printing of *Effective Java* 3rd Ed), so people do... weird things, "just in case".

Comment: Side bar: [What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `while` loop there is unnecessary.

Each of the loops will only execute zero or one times, so they are equivalent to if.